# PHP PDO is ruining my $_POST values?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

EDIT: Edit of the original code: (I changed the if to "if($_POST['Break'] != "")" to test it and it doesnt work, neither do any of the other varients that i've tried.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
{
    echo '<form method="post" action="">
        Category name: <input type="text" name="cat_name" />
        Category description: <textarea name="cat_description" /></textarea>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Break">Is Table Break?<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add category" />
     </form>';
}


$sql= 'INSERT INTO categories(cat_name, cat_description, isheader) VALUES (:cat_name, :cat_description, :isheader)';
         $stmt = $DBH->prepare($sql);
          if($_POST['Break'] != ""){
          $isbreak = true;
          }
          else{
          $isbreak = false;
          }         
        $stmt->bindParam(':cat_name', $_POST['cat_name']); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':cat_description', $_POST['cat_description']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':isheader', $isbreak);
        try{
           $stmt->execute();
           header('Location: /testpage.php');
        }
        catch(PDOexception $e){
          $e->getMessage();
        }
```

The above code should insert into my database with Column "Break" being set to "True"(or 1) when a checkbox is checked. It doesnt. I've tried the following if statements and none fixed it:

```
if(isset($_POST['Break']) == 1)
if(($_POST['Break']) == "Break")  - ("Break" being the name of my checkbox.
if(($_POST['Break']) === "Break") 
if(($_POST['Break']) == 'Break')
```

Now i know this code SHOULD work because before i converted to PDO php it was working. Heres what my previous code looked like. This was 100% working how i wanted it to:

```
if(isset($_POST['Break']) == 1){
   $isbreak = true;
}
else{
    $isbreak = false;
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO categories(cat_name, cat_description, isheader)
           VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cat_name']) . "',
                 '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cat_description']) . "', ". $isbreak.")";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$result)
    {
        echo 'Error' . mysql_error();
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: /testpage.php');
    };
```

I know some of the $_POST data works because my database is filled with the correct "cat_name" and "cat_description" with the PDO code. I've had this problem for EVERY page on my site converting it. I've managed to find dumb little work around specific to each page, but i cant figure this one out. I'd rather just know why this is acting the way it is.

What's more is that when i do print_r($_POST) and my check box is checked it returns the value "Break". I dont understand it.

Comment: What does your `print_r($_POST)` show? That will show you exactly what to check for. Normally `isset($_POST['checkbox_name'])` will be either true or false, and from memory if you don't define a value to the element its value will be 'on'

Comment: @scrowler print_r($_POST) prints this exactly: "Array ( [cat_name] => fff [cat_description] => fff [Break] => Break )"
When i have the box checked and other fields set to "fff". Sorry i pressed enter before i was done typing this.

Comment: @scrowler I removed the "name" and "value" attributes from my checkbox and now its not even recognize in post.

Comment: Question, why are you using `"true"` and `"false"` as strings? If converted to a boolean (or integer in you table?), won't they both evaluate to true (non-empty)?

Comment: Another question, looks like you're only inserting into the table (`execute()`) if the check box is selected, meaning all inserted values would have the same 'true' value.

Comment: @user3521471 if you remove the `name` attribute, the element won't get sent in a form. The `name` attribute is required for it to actually be posted.

Comment: @MichaelWheeler I've tried strings and non strings neither work at the moment. And yeah i forgot to edit that out. I set it to only execute if it is true just to test it. Even with that set, it always inserts to false.

Comment: Sorry for all of the questions, what happens when you add $e->getMessage(); in the catch block? Have you set the PDO error attribute to exception `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` ?

Comment: @MichaelWheeler Its okay, I do have the exception line set. And when i added that to the catch block, it doesnt display any message. I assume because it never hits the catch block.

Comment: Could you update your post with the form and the current version of the code in question?

Comment: Also another point on the why i use string values for $isbreak. It gets put into the sql statement as a string anyway so it doesnt matter.

Comment: @MichaelWheeler Just added new code

Comment: @MichaelWheeler Oops let me add the form

Comment: Your checkbox does not have the name parameter set.

Comment: In regards to a recently deleted question of yours... please see: http://jsfiddle.net/7zHL9/2/

Comment: @JonP thanks for the response even if i deleted it. Your jsfiddle page still pushed the yellow "right" div down though.

Comment: @user3521471 easy fix, was just a large top yellow boarder. See http://jsfiddle.net/7zHL9/3/. I thought that was the effect you were looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why i use string values for $isbreak. It gets put into the sql statement as a string anyway so it doesnt matter.

Yes, it does matter.

The string `'true'` in an integer context has the value 0 in MySQL. Any string-to-integer conversion that happens implicitly takes the leading digit characters from the string, and if there are none, the string has the value zero.

Whereas the keyword `true` is exactly equal to the integer 1.

Here's a demo of the conversion. I'm adding + 0 to force the values to be converted to integers.

```
mysql> select 'true' + 0;
+------------+
| 'true' + 0 |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+

mysql> select true + 0;
+----------+
| true + 0 |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
```

In your old code, you put the `true` keyword into your INSERT statement, so the MySQL server ended up seeing the following:

```
INSERT INTO categories(cat_name, cat_description, isheader)
    VALUES('name', 'description', true)
```

When `true` is inserted into an integer column, the value inserted is 1.

But when passing strings as parameters, they are sent as strings, so it works similar* to the following:

```
INSERT INTO categories(cat_name, cat_description, isheader)
    VALUES('name', 'description', 'true')
```

When `'true'` is inserted into an integer column, the value inserted is 0.

---

Re your comment:

It makes no difference if you're using PDO or non-PDO. If you interpolate an unquoted string into an SQL statement, it is parsed as a keyword. If you pass a string as a parameter, it's similar to interpolating a *quoted* string into the SQL statement, and therefore `'true'` becomes 0 in an integer context.

---

I worked up a more thorough test script. I guess you got your answer, it was actually an HTML form problem, not an SQL problem. But I'll post my test script here anyway for future reference.

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO(..., array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO foo (test, boolcol) VALUES ('test 1: literal true', true)");
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO foo (test, boolcol) VALUES ('test 2: literal \'true\'', 'true')");
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO foo (test, boolcol) VALUES ('test 3: literal 1', 1)");
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO foo (test, boolcol) VALUES ('test 4: literal \'1\'', '1')");
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO foo (test, boolcol) VALUES ('test 5: param true', ?)");
$stmt->execute(array(true));

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO foo (test, boolcol) VALUES ('test 6: param \'true\'', ?)");
$stmt->execute(array('true'));

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO foo (test, boolcol) VALUES ('test 7: param 1', ?)");
$stmt->execute(array(1));

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO foo (test, boolcol) VALUES ('test 8: param \'1\'', ?)");
$stmt->execute(array('1'));
```

Here's the result:

```
+------------------------+---------+
| test                   | boolcol |
+------------------------+---------+
| test 1: literal true   |       1 |
| test 2: literal 'true' |       0 |
| test 3: literal 1      |       1 |
| test 4: literal '1'    |       1 |
| test 5: param true     |       1 |
| test 6: param 'true'   |       0 |
| test 7: param 1        |       1 |
| test 8: param '1'      |       1 |
+------------------------+---------+
```

---

* *Parameters are never combined with the SQL syntax, they're combined with an internal representation of the query logic during execution, but after the SQL has already been parsed. That's why I say "similar."*

Comment: I see what youre saying and i understand the concept, but thats not what is happening. My statement was in regards to the nonPDO version. It worked either way. Inserting like so:$sql = "INSERT INTO categories(cat_name, cat_description, isheader)
       VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cat_name']) . "',
             '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cat_description']) . "', ". $isbreak.")";

Turns $isbreak into a string anyway, no?

Comment: Let me rephrase, it adds the value of $isbreak into &sql as a string.

Comment: @user3521471 What if you try `$stmt->bindParam(':isheader', $isbreak, PDO::PARAM_BOOL)` and use `$isbreak = true;`

Comment: The thing is it works correctly when my old code has "true" and "false" as values to $isbreak, and the new code doesnt work when true and false are values for $isbreak.

Comment: @MichaelWheeler My code is exactly the same as above only with your edit. Still inserts to 0.

Comment: @MichaelWheeler, check the code in ext/pdo_mysql. Most of the `PDO::PARAM` type arguments are ignored. Only if the type is `PDO::PARAM_BLOB` or `PDO::PARAM_NULL` does it do anything besides send a string. Maybe these type arguments are used differently in other PDO drivers.

Comment: @user3521471 (1) did you add the name parameter back into the checkbox? (2) what happens when you `var_dump($isbreak);` before/after the bindParam()?

Comment: @MichaelWheeler Yeah that did it! I still dont get it though because on other pages when i have text inputs assigned name attributes, it still doesnt let me use "isset" i have to compare it to ""(empty string, but not null). Anyway thank you for all of the help on getting this page fixed. And thanks BillKarwin for the explanation.

Comment: Maybe I can copy & paste this answer for another StackOverflow question where the answer is actually relevant to the root cause of the problem! :-)